# Set literal gives different result from set function call

Tags: python, hash, set, python-2.x, python-internals

Why does the `set` function call wipe out the dupes, but parsing a set literal does not?

```
>>> x = Decimal('0')
>>> y = complex(0,0)
>>> set([0, x, y])
{0}
>>> {0, x, y}
{Decimal('0'), 0j}
```

(Python 2.7.12.  Possibly same root cause as for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40225520/674039) similar question)

Comment: related: [Dict/Set Parsing Order Consistency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34623846/4279)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Sets test for equality, and until there are new Python releases, the order in which they do this can differ based on the form you hand the values to the set being constructed, as I'll show below.

Since `0 == x` is true *and* `0 == y` is true, but `x == y` is *false*, the behaviour here is really *undefined*, as the set assumes that `x == y` must be true if the first two tests were true too.

If you *reverse* the list passed to `set()`, then you get the same output as using a literal, because the order of equality tests changes:

```
>>> set([y, x, 0])
set([0j, Decimal('0')])
```

and the same for reversing the literal:

```
>>> {y, x, 0}
set([0])
```

What's happening is that the set *literal* loads the values onto the stack and then the stack values are added to the new set object in reverse order.

As long as `0` is loaded *first*, the other two objects are then tested against `0` already in the set. The moment one of the other two objects is loaded first, the equality test fails and you get two objects added:

```
>>> {y, 0, x}
set([Decimal('0'), 0j])
>>> {x, 0, y}
set([0j, Decimal('0')])
```

That set literals add elements in reverse is a bug present in all versions of Python that support the syntax, all the way until Python 2.7.12 and 3.5.2. It was recently fixed, see [issue 26020](http://bugs.python.org/issue26020) (part of 2.7.13, 3.5.3 and 3.6, none of which have been released yet). If you look at 2.7.12, you can see that [`BUILD_SET` in `ceval.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.12/Python/ceval.c#l2478) reads the stack from the top down:

```c
# oparg is the number of elements to take from the stack to add
for (; --oparg >= 0;) {
    w = POP();
    if (err == 0)
        err = PySet_Add(x, w);
    Py_DECREF(w);
}
```

while the bytecode adds elements to the stack in reverse order (pushing `0` on the stack first):

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis(compile('{0, x, y}', '', 'eval'))
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (x)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (y)
              9 BUILD_SET                3
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

The fix is to read the elements from the stack in reverse order; the [Python 2.7.13 version](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a8d504600c18/Python/ceval.c#l2478) uses `PEEK()` instead of `POP()` (and a `STACKADJ()` to remove the elements from the stack afterwards):

```c
for (i = oparg; i > 0; i--) {
    w = PEEK(i);
    if (err == 0)
        err = PySet_Add(x, w);
    Py_DECREF(w);
}
STACKADJ(-oparg);
```

The equality testing issue has the same root cause as the other question; the `Decimal()` class is having some equality issues with `complex` here, which was fixed in Python 3.2 (by making [`Decimal()` support comparisons to `complex` and a few other numeric types it didn't support before](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/26685311d313/)).

Comment: Do you think it's a bug that equality is not transitive for these three types?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: I think so, yes. Why shouldn't `0j` be equal to `Decimal('0')` when `0j == 0` is true and `Decimal('0') == 0` is also true. Python 3.2 fixed this by updating the `Decimal` comparisons.

Comment: `bytearray('ab') == 'ab' == u'ab'` is also breaking transitivity, but since `bytearray` are not hashable it is of no consequence there.

Comment: Issue 26020 is interesting.  It seems the more serious bug is that `complex` equality is misbehaving, so I'm surprised that didn't get a fix in python 2 yet.

Comment: @wim: `complex` sees far less use than `set()` does. Besides, it's a bug in `Decimal`, not `complex`.

Answer (score 7):

It's all down to the order in which the set is constructed, combined with the bug you discovered with [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40225520/296974).  It appears that the literal is constructed in the opposite order to conversion from a list.

```
>>> {0, x, y}
set([0j, Decimal('0')])
>>> {y, x, 0}
set([0])
```

Comment: Ah, yes that's insightful.  How about a cpython source reference that shows how the literal is parsed right-to-left ?

Comment: @wim: I had trouble finding the code for that, only because the bug was recently fixed.

Comment: @wim as fun as that sounds, I've never gone spelunking through the Python source code.